# How to check if a web element does not have another inner web element

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test, I need to check if a web element does not have another web element inside it, for example:

```
<div><span>bla bla</span></div>
<div><g></g></div>
<div><li></li></div>
```

I need to select the `div` tags which does not have `<span>` inside them, so do we have something like:

```
//div[not(.//span[text()='bla bla'])]
```

Please do not tell me how to do it in other ways as I already know, I am just wondering if I can do it in a way like the one above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath should've done what you wanted. It will select `<div>` element that doesn't contain, either direct child or nested, `span` element with text equals `"bla bla"`. See the demo online : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/be01362aa9bb1385da6dcf819cf69376

**input :**

```
<div> 
  <div>
    <span>bla bla</span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <g/>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <li/>
  </div> 
</div>
```

**output :**

```
<div>
    <g/>
  </div>

<div>
    <li/>
  </div>
```